# Unsolicited remote assistance

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am trying to figure out how to allow a group of users to offer unsolicited remote assistance using `msra /offerra` to their fellow domain members.

I have created a policy enabling "Offer Remote Assistance" and filling the `DOMAIN\RAHelpers` user group into the "Helpers" list. I can see the `DOMAIN\RAHelpers` group turning up as a member in the local "Offer Remote Assistance Helpers" group of the targeted domain computers after the policy is applied. Yet, I am unable to set up a remote assistance connection with one of these users ***unless*** they are also a member of the local *Administrators* group of the to-be-assisted machine. The error message is rather unspecific (*"Your offer to help could not be sent"*), but I suspect a DCOM permission issue since RA seems to use DCOM and local administrators can connect for help just fine.

What minimal permission set would I need to allow for unsolicited remote assistance? I obviously do not want to promote all helpers to local administrators.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out to be as easy as adding the users to the *"Distributed COM Users"* local group.

The "Enable remote assistance" policy does not change this group's memberships and unsolicited remote assistance seems to depend on DCOM remote activation.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the issue with RA not working was due to a mismatch in encryption.

Domain Controllers were using RC4 and Windows 10 clients are using AES128/256/future.

```
2.3.11.4 (L1) Ensure 'Network security: Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos' is set to 'AES128_HMAC_SHA1, AES256_HMAC_SHA1, Future encryption types'
```