# Unsolicited Remote Assistance on domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, remote, remote-desktop-services

I manage a domain using win 2k8 r2 and 100 PC on Windows7. I have configured the Unsolicited Remote Assistance proceeding with all the requirements posted here
https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-enable-unsolicited-remote-assistance-in-windows-7-8/
or
http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/210-offer-unsolicited-remote-assistance-to-ms-domain-computers

Is there a way to bypass this rule: "Any users offering help will need to be a local administrator on the system being helped." ?

I am always stacked on the black screen pause button every time that I have to do a elevation action, my users are simple user with no administrative rights, and my account is a domain admin

I tested this solution
[Unsolicited remote assistance](https://serverfault.com/questions/591017/unsolicited-remote-assistance)
with a Security group added on the local PC but still no changes.

Comment: Can you double check the relevant part from the article: "Navigate to Computer Configuration> Policies> Windows Settings> Security Settings> Local Policies> Security Options, then enable the User Account Control: Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop policy."

Comment: yes i triple checked that